# Adding a vector as a new column to a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

MyDataframe is a dataframe which has 7 columns now of the character, numeric and date data types. The dataframe has 300,000 rows.

I need to have a vector as a new field for each row of the data table. I need the vector to have 1440 zeros initially. Let's call this MyVector.

If I try this:

> MyDataframe$MyVector = numeric(1440)

I get an error message saying that the number of rows in the dataframe dont match the length of the vector. This tells me that R is trying to add the whole vector as a column in the dataframe.

How do I add the vector, so that each row of the dataframe will have a vector as a member?

Comment: Someting like `MyDataframe$MyVector <- lapply(1:(dim(MyDataframe)[1]), function(x) matrix(0,1440) )` should do it, but will need about 3.5GB of RAM

Comment: Your text is not describing your issue well. Please show desired results with example data?

Comment: I am asking whether a dataframe can have a column of the data type vector. In other words, can every row have a member that is a vector?

Comment: Would you please edit it, so it become more clear for future visiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `data.frame` is a special type of `list`. It can have any kind of object in it: others lists (such as models), data.frames or even vectors. In those cases, the data.frame is known as **nested data.frame**, that's the term you need to search for.

You can produce it like this:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = letters[1:3])
df$vectors <- list(numeric(3), numeric(3), numeric(3))
str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a      : int  1 2 3
 $ b      : Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
 $ vectors:List of 3
  ..$ : num  0 0 0
  ..$ : num  0 0 0
  ..$ : num  0 0 0
```